Azure PubSub - shuts off randomly after days
I'm trying to troubleshoot one of our pubsub listeners running in a docker container on a aws instance randomly shutting off after few days.
It is written in nodejs using this sdk which is
I observed there is no spike in cpu or memory. The container is running but pubsub connection closes and it is after random set of days.
Following is the snippet which I have a re-connect mechanism. I see the service close log message but it never gets to the re-connect.
Appreciate any suggestions to troubleshoot.
function connect(ws: WebSocket) {
  ws.on('error', (error) => console.log(error));
  ws.on('open', () =>
    console.log(
      '******** Pubsub listening to messages! ********* ',
      new Date().toISOString()
    )
  );
  ws.on('close', (e) => {
    console.log(
      'Service connection is CLOSED. Reconnect will be attempted in 5s.',
      e
    );
    setTimeout(function () {
      connect(ws);
    }, 5000);
  });
  ws.on('message', async (data) => {
    console.log('Message received: %s %s', data, new Date().toISOString());
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
  });
}


Check that container is not hitting any CPU limits

It's already mentioned above.
